# How to update image in DataGridView's column with type Text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that is being populated by a `List`. I will send an email and if it is OK I put `status = "S"` as follows:

```
var query = (from send in SendMsg
             where send.MessageSentId == str
             select send)
    .Update(st => { st.EmailST = EmailSt; st.SMSST = "N"; });

gvSent.DataSource = null;
gvSent.DataSource = SendMsg;
```

Everything is working, only now I need to put 2 images containing Ok or Not Ok status. Using the code below, instead of my grid displaying image, it is showing a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` text. I suspect it is because the column is with type `Text` and not `Image`. But this `DataGridView` is dynamic and I cannot define the types of columns.

```
private void gvSent_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (gvSent.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "EmailST")
    {
        if (gvSent.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value == "S")
        {
            e.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.IMAGE8;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.IMAGE9;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't show an image in a text column as you have already surmised, so what is your question exactly? I think you should be asking how to create a grid dynamically and derive the column data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *this `DataGridView` is dynamic*, it means that its columns are constructed from the data binding. So change the type in your data binding for that column and replace its data with the images before you bind the `DataGridView`. In such a case, you can use another class or simply an anonymous class:

```
var sent = SendMsg.Select(s => new {
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.Name,
    EmailST = (s.EmailST == "S"? (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.IMAGE8
                               : (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.IMAGE9)
}).ToList();

gvSent.DataSource = null;
gvSent.DataSource = sent;
```

The fields `Id` and `Name` are just example, because I don't know what fields your `SendMsg` class has. The idea is that you can build an anonymous class based on your `SendMsg` class and transfer some fields while modifying some other fields.

Alternatively, you can define the columns in the grid (so it is no more dynamic).